# Region not loaded by the RegionManger

Tags: prism

in  a prism 6 based application, 
this is a part of my shell, and **QuickAccessToolBar** region defined like this:

```
<telerik:RadRibbonView>
        <telerik:RadRibbonView.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <telerik:QuickAccessToolBar prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.QuickAccessToolBarRegion}"/>
        </telerik:RadRibbonView.QuickAccessToolBar>
```

The **RegionManger** will not be loads the region,

and when will replace the definition above(just for demo purposes) by this :

```
<telerik:RadRibbonView >
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.QuickAccessToolBarRegion}"/>
```

The RegionManager loads the region!

**my question is:**
what's Wrong in my XAML ? my be the region was defined inside a complex property?
Can you guide me, 
thanks in advance.
best regards.

### **Solution :**

Very good answer Brian, it works like a charm, 
as **Brian** said:

1. first of all we name the targeted element:

```
<telerik:RadRibbonView.QuickAccessToolBar>
    <telerik:QuickAccessToolBar x:Name="QuickAccessToolBar"/>
</telerik:RadRibbonView.QuickAccessToolBar>
```

2. in the code behind (the Shell in my case) :

```
public Shell(ShellViewModel viewModel, IRegionManager regionManager)
{ 
 InitializeComponent();
 DataContext = viewModel;
 RegionManager.SetRegionName(QuickAccessToolBar,RegionNames.QuickAccessToolBarRegion);
 RegionManager.SetRegionManager(QuickAccessToolBar, regionManager);
}
```

**Where RegionNames.QuickAccessToolBarRegion ="QuickAccessToolBarRegion" and regionManager is the RegionManager resolved by unity container**

Thank you very much Brian, good night :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the QuickAccessTolbar is not part of the visual tree, so the region manager can't find it.  Since this is a Telerik control, I am not aware of how they architected their control.  You might have to do this in code behind instead.

First set the region name, then set the RegionManager using the attached properties.

RegionManager.SetRegionName(quickToolbar, name);

RegionManager.SetRegionManager(quickToolbar, rm);