# RegionManager shows no Region

Tags: prism, autofac

I am pretty new to DI / Prism etc and trying to teach myself.  I am  deriving from  AutofacBootstrapper that is an add on for Prism 6. Shell initialization is fine but having trouble with understanding module registration.

```
public class MyBootstrapper : AutofacBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window) Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void InitializeModules()
    {
         base.InitializeModules();
         var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
         var regionManager = new RegionManager(); 
         builder.RegisterInstance(regionManager).As<IRegionManager>(); 
         builder.Register(c => new ModuleAModule(c.Resolve<IRegionManager>()));
         var container = builder.Build();
         using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
         {
             var component = scope.Resolve<ModuleAModule>();
             component.Initialize();
         }
     }
}


public class ModuleAModule : IModule
{
    private IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private IContainer _container;
    public ModuleAModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ToolbarRegion, typeof(ToolbarView));
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegion, typeof(ContentView));
    }
}
```

The shell comes up fine with 2 regions, however at the end of Initialize I am checking _regionManager.Regions.Count and getting 0 instead of 2 as I would have created 2 regions.
The xaml is below.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="Shell">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock ="Top" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static wpfApplication1:RegionNames.ToolbarRegion}"/>
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static wpfApplication1:RegionNames.ContentRegion}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

RegionNames is simple...

```
public static class RegionNames
{
    public static readonly string ToolbarRegion = "ToolbarRegion";
    public static readonly string ContentRegion = "ContentRegion";
}
```

So my question is why would RegionManager would have no Regions?

Comment: I think the problem of the visual tree, take look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607639/region-not-loaded-by-the-regionmanger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Prism v6 you are using the wrong namespace its:

```
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
```

and then it works.

Here are my code for the ContentView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.ContentView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="Blue">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the ToolbarView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.ToolbarView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Grid Background="Aqua" Height="20">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Edit:

Sorry I forgote a part.

```
public void Initialize()
{
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ToolbarRegion, typeof(ToolbarView));
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegion, typeof(ContentView));

    Console.WriteLine(_regionManager.Regions.Count());
}
```

If you set a Breakpoint at the Console.WriteLine you see at that point now view is injected to the Region. Thats because the Initialize of the bootstrapper isn't done. You see that at the output window.

**DEBUG: Initializing modules.. Priority: Low. Timestamp:2015-12-17 09:58:09Z.**

**0** <-- Console.WriteLine(_regionManager.Regions.Count());

**DEBUG: Bootstrapper sequence completed.. Priority: Low. Timestamp:2015-12-17 09:58:09Z.** <-- Boostrapper completed :-)

If you ask later in your programm now you will get the 2.

I hope now that helps ;-)

Comment: Hello ascholz, Thank you for responding. I have fixed the namespace, but even before that the UI have come up fine as it does now. When you put a breakpoint at the the end of Intialize() in ModuleAModule  class, what do you get for _regionManager.Regions.Count? I get 0, but I don't understand why, as I expected the count to be 2.

Comment: If that was the answere you looking for? If yes please mark the question as answered :-)